# How to tag emails with symfony/mailer and symfony/mailgun-mailer provider

Tags: symfony, mailgun, mailer

In my project where I use Mailgun to send emails, I want to tag emails as described [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#tagging). But I can't find how to do that with symfony/mailer and symfony/mailgun-mailer provider and can't find any documentation about that, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution and want to share it with other developers. I add `"X-Mailgun-Tag"` header and it works.

```
$message = (new TemplatedEmail())
      ->from(new NamedAddress($senderEmail, $senderName))
      ->to(new NamedAddress($receiverEmail, $receiverName))
      ->subject($subject)
      ->htmlTemplate($template)
      ->context($context);

$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', $tag1);
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', $tag2);
```